# How to read from a file which has SQL script which needs to be executed on multiple DBs on same server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Below script suppose to be executed on multiple DBs,  however on parsing gives below error-

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 40
Incorrect syntax near '+'.

```
declare @list table (name varchar(128) not null);

fill the list with your custom subset
insert into @list
select name from sys.databases where name like '%connect%';

--select * from @list
--select min(name) from @list

--read the script
declare
    @DBServerName varchar(128),
    @FilePathName varchar(128),
    @DBName varchar(128)
;

set @DBServerName = 'peeyushp-w8';
set @FilePathName = 'D:\script.sql';
set @DBName = '';

--EXEC xp_cmdshell  'sqlcmd -S ' + @DBServerName + ' -d  ' + @DBName + ' -i ' + @FilePathName


declare
    @db varchar(128),
    @t varchar(max),
    @s varchar(max)
;

--set @t = 'use {db}; exec sp_spaceused';

set @db = (select min(name) from @list);

while @db is not null
begin
    --set @s = replace(@t, '{db}', ' -d' + @db);

    --exec (@s);
    EXEC xp_cmdshell  'sqlcmd -S ' + @DBServerName + @s + ' -i ' + replace(@FilePathName, '{db}', ' -d' + @db);

    set @db = (select min(name) from @list where name > @db);
end
GO
```

Error is coming on 'xp_cmdshell' exec statement. Am i missing something which to be included in my SQL script. Will appreciate any help on the same.

Answer (score 1):

According to [PROCEDURE's Limitations and Restrictions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx#Anchor_5) in T-SQL :

> You cannot specify a function name as a parameter default value or as the value passed to a parameter when executing a procedure. However, you can pass a function as a variable as shown in the following example.

So, it is impossible to use directly the string concatenation as procedure parameter. It must be declared before :

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(400)
SET @cmd = 'sqlcmd -S ' + @DBServerName + ' -d  ' + @DBName + ' -i ' + @FilePathName

-- Now you can use it
EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd
```